Non-conformable arguments only when using a "chopped" (g)lmer model object
I am fitting a model with somewhat collinear predictors, and then predicting out of it. This works fine when using the original model object, but for performance reasons, I want to save a "chopped"/reduced-size version of the model, and then load that reduced model again later to make predictions.
Despite the collinearity, I am able to predict() using the full model, but when I attempt the same operation with the reduced-size model, I get
Error in X %*% fixef(object) : non-conformable arguments

What can I add to the glmer_chop() function that will let me predict out of the reduced_model with no issues, just as I can with original_model?
Reprex:
library(lme4)

# This is intended to reduce the size of the (g)lmer object
glmer_chop <- function(object) {
  newobj <- object
  newobj@frame <- model.frame(object)[0, 1:ncol(model.frame(object))]
  attr(newobj@frame, "terms") <- attr(object@frame, "terms")
  newobj@pp <- with(object@pp,
                    new("merPredD",
                        Lambdat=Lambdat,
                        Lind=Lind,
                        theta=theta,
                        delu=delu,
                        u=u,u0=u0,
                        n=nrow(X),
                        X=matrix(1,nrow=nrow(X)),
                        Zt=Zt))
  newobj@resp <- new("glmResp",family=binomial(),y=numeric(0))
  return(newobj)
}

original_model <- glmer(vs ~
                         disp +
                         hp +
                          I(cyl > 6) +  # These two vars are correlated
                         factor(cyl) +  # These two vars are correlated
                         (1 | am),
                        family = "binomial",
                       data = mtcars)
summary(original_model)

reduced_model <- glmer_chop(original_model)

mtcars$pred_original <- mtcars$pred_reduced <- NA

# Predicting from full model works
mtcars$pred_original <- predict(original_model, newdata = mtcars, type = "response")

# Predicting from reduced model errors with:
# Error in X %*% fixef(object) : non-conformable arguments
mtcars$pred_reduced <- predict(reduced_model, newdata = mtcars, type = "response")


It turns out only a small change is needed: in the @pp slot, keep all of the original X, not just a reduced matrix version of it.
glmer_chop <- function(object) {
  newobj <- object
  newobj@frame <- model.frame(object)[0, 1:ncol(model.frame(object))]
  attr(newobj@frame, "terms") <- attr(object@frame, "terms")
  newobj@pp <- with(object@pp,
                    new("merPredD",
                        Lambdat=Lambdat,
                        Lind=Lind,
                        theta=theta,
                        delu=delu,
                        u=u,u0=u0,
                        n=nrow(X),
                        X=X, # THIS IS THE CHANGE
                        Zt=Zt))
  newobj@resp <- new("glmResp",family=binomial(),y=numeric(0))
  return(newobj)
}

Here's why: predict() calls fixef(), which in turn calls getME(), which retrieves the entire X.  fixef() uses that object to assign dimnames to the fixed effects; without them, the matrix multiplication fails.  (The reason it fails is not clear to me, but that's how it is.)  Compare the output of fixef() for the original and reduced models:
> fixef(original_model)
   (Intercept)           disp             hp I(cyl > 6)TRUE   factor(cyl)6 
    335.504295      -1.398626       1.096582  -23793.196306     -76.846436 
> fixef(reduced_model)
[1]    335.504295     -1.398626      1.096582 -23793.196306    -76.846436

With the edit above, the reduced model looks like the original model.
> fixef(revised_reduced_model)
   (Intercept)           disp             hp I(cyl > 6)TRUE   factor(cyl)6 
    335.504295      -1.398626       1.096582  -23793.196306     -76.846436


This is nice. It would not be too hard (I think) to modify the structure of the code slightly to make storing the full X unnecessary (e.g., store the column names of X as part of the model structure and add a method to getME to retrieve this information. If this is an important use case for you (the X matrix could be very large ...) please post an issue

PS what happens if you keep just the first row, i.e. X = X[1,] ... ?  That would preserve the dimnames ...

Keeping just the first row of X should work for fixef(), but it looks like it runs into other problems with the merPredD class - so not that straightforward, unfortunately.  (Plain X[1,] resulted in a type error, so I used as.matrix(X[1,,drop=F]), which led to a "non-conformable arguments" error...it looks like the rows are needed somewhere else.)

Well, if you want this pursued farther please feel free to post an issue and I/we can look into it at some point -- there may be some way to make this work without having X present ...

Thanks so much for your answer; this seems to have solved the problem, and without blowing up the size of the chopped object.
